# Jquery UI Rotatable is not working for a text box on canvas

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-resizable

I am using this [Image Maker jquery plugin](https://github.com/mattar88/imageMaker), it creates memes and images with text boxes that can be draggable and resizable. However, it does not have the rotating option.
I tried to rotate by [jQuery UI Rotatable](https://github.com/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable) plugin that is:
It rotates the text box handles, but not rotating the text within it. The live demo is [here](https://pakunit.net/imgmaker/demo/)

please help me to rotate the text within the text box resizable. Thanks